# Line at edge of transparent texture on XNA mesh

Tags: xna, textures, transparency, antialiasing

I have a mesh that is computer generated with a texture on top of it with transparancy on one side. The SamplerState is set to LinearWrap because I would like the texture to wrap. The problem I have is that this transparent edge has some weird aliasing. This does not occur when I set the SamplerState to LinearClamp.

I found that when letting the U coordinate go from 0.1 to 0.9 this does not happen. Probably on the transparent side it interpolates U coordinate 1 with U coordinate 0.

What could be the solution to prevent aside from not letting the U coordinate go all the way to 1?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new SamplerState of your own and set it like this:

```
mySampler.Filter = TextureFilter.Linear;
mySampler.AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Clamp;
mySampler.AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
mySampler.AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
```

The V coordinate will be wrapped (since you want horizontal repeat) and the U will be clamped.